# Do I need use sharedInstace inside sharedInstace's class?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I got class for web requests and responses, to call it I use 'sharedInstace'.

Inside that class I use a lot of methods, that configure my final request to web server.

Do I need to use inside every that method call to 'sharedInstace' or I can use 'self'?

Comment: it doesn't really matter, but i would use self

Comment: your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should use `self` for all "internal" method calls of your class
that are done to process a request.
That makes it easier to change your design from
a shared instance to multiple instances later, e.g. if you have to process two or
more web requests at the same time.

And actually I would not use a shared instance at all. Better create one instance for
each web request.